# WCF: set different timeouts for different operations

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have WCF service which contains 3 opearations

- Authentication
- logAuthentivationTimeout
- CalculateMonthlyData

I am consuming this web serice from my WPF application. I need to set different time out for the different functions. Is this possible?

I need to set the time out for `Authentication` operation from the WPF application itself.

`Authentication` operations needs to timeout the operation if it exceeds 30 seconds. But the `CalculateMonthlyData` must need to wait at least 4 minutes to timeout the operation.

How can I do this? Please suggest a best approach.

Comment: Duplicate of [Change timeout for each WCF method or call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954680/change-timeout-for-each-wcf-method-or-call), [WCF configuring timeout “per Operation”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779307/wcf-configuring-timeout-per-operation) and others. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted a similar question, and answer, here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/8577cd13-b86a-4273-8a7f-c1aabc37ef95